# Which is more Pythonic calling __str__() method or casting to str()?

Tags: python

I have a wrapper class for a dictionary object and I'm curious if one is preferred over the other when implementing the `__repr__` method in my class:

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._obj = dict()
  def __repr__(self):
    return self._obj.__str__()
```

OR

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._obj = dict()
  def __repr__(self):
    return str(self._obj)
```

The second implementation with `str()` feels right to me. I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right. You should avoid calling the double underscore methods directly: the built-in functions are the Pythonic way of doing this.

(The same is true for example for `len(foo)` vs `foo.__len__()`.)

Comment: I'd personally add the one time you are supposed to use double underscore methods- `super().__init__()`

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself this: **if `__str__` was available, why would people use `str`?**

`__str__` is just the overload you can use if you want to modify the default `str` method. Likewise for `__len__`.

Would you use this?

```
print(1.__add__(2))
```

---

**An answer philosophy:** Demonstrate core understanding to the asker, preferably having the asker conclude the correct answer by themselves.